# How to load static file from JavaScript in Django?

Tags: javascript, django, ecmascript-6, django-staticfiles, static-files

Hello so I have been trying to play an audio element in my Django app and controlling it using JavaScript. I was trying to play the audio from localhost, but I got the following errors:
[image]

And I guess it's because I made a mistake in loading the audio file in my JS code.

```
import AudioPlayer from './AudioPlayer.js';

const audioPlayer = new AudioPlayer('.audioPlayer', [
    {url: '../music/rainfall.mp3', name: 'Alleviating Rainfall'},
]);
```

I think I did wrong on the url: part so django does not load my mp3 file and serve it from the server. So my question is, how can I load static audio file in Django from JS? I know for HTML it's {% static "[filepath]" %} but what's for JS?? Since the JS itself is a static file.. Here's my file directory:
[image]

Comment: You can't use Django templating in a static file. You either have to hardcode the URL, or call your static JS file from a function in a dynamic HTML file, where you'll pass the URL as a variable.